# Under Zariski topology , $ \operatorname{Spec} k[X,Y] \cong \operatorname{Spec} k[X] \times \operatorname{Spec}k[Y]$?

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, commutative-algebra, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. Consider the topological space $B= \operatorname{Spec}k[X]$ with usual Zariski topology. Then is it true that with Zariski topology, $B \times B$ is homeomorphic with $ \operatorname{Spec} k[X,Y]$   ?

Comment: What do you mean by $B \times B$? Is this the space with the product topology or the product of varieties? In the former case what you say is false in general, in the latter it's true since $k[X] \otimes_k k[Y] \cong k[X,Y]$

Comment: @leibnewtz: I mean product of varieties. Why is it true ? Could you please explain (as an answer) or give some references ? Thanks ..

Comment: @leibnewtz: In the latter its false in general; rather than a product of varieties, you have in mind the fiber product over $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ (or equivalently, a product of "varieties over $k$")

Comment: @Hurkyl: could you please give some explanations ?

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, you're right. I was thinking of the product in the category of varieties over $k$.

Comment: @users You should try to prove $k[X] \otimes_k k[Y]$ yourself, it's not bad at all. Hint: What is an obvious map $k[X] \otimes_k k[Y] \to k[X,Y]$? The fact that this implies $\mathbb{A}^1 \times_k \mathbb{A}^1 \cong \mathbb{A}^2$ is just an expression of that fact that $Spec(A \otimes_k B) \cong Spec(A) \times_k Spec(B)$.

Comment: @leibnewtz: yes the tensor product isomorphism I can prove. But I don't know about the fact about the spectrum of tensor product ... could you please give an argument or some reference ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit too long for a comment, so I'll add it here. The fiber product of two schemes $X$ and $Y$ over $k$ satisfies a universal property: It is the pullback of the diagram $X \to Spec(k) \leftarrow Y$. In other words, if we have a $k$ scheme $Z$ with maps of $k$ schemes $Z \to X$ and $Z \to Y$ making the obvious diagram commute, we get a unique map $Z \to X \times_k Y$.

It follows that to show $Spec(A \otimes_k B) \cong Spec(A) \times_k Spec(B)$ we just need to show that $Spec(A \otimes_k B)$ satisfies the universal property above. Since the $Spec$ functor induces a contravariant equivalence of categories between $k$-algebras and affine schemes over $k$, we need to show that $A \otimes_k B$ satisfies the dual universal property in the category of $k$-algebras. Try to show that a map $A \otimes_k B \to R$ of $k$ algebras is the same as a pair of maps of $k$-algebras $A \to R$ and $B \to R$. Use this to conclude the desired isomorphism.